# git: put THEIR commits AFTER my commits with a single rebase command

Tags: git

Suppose master and origin/master diverged.
I'm on master and I want to put the commits from origin/master after my commits and then push --force.

```
     A---B---C origin/master
    /
D---E---F---G *master

     A---B---C origin/master
    /
D---E---F---G---A'---B'---C' *master
```

Variant 1:

```
git branch -f tmp
git reset --hard origin/master
git rebase tmp
```

This variant is bad, because 'git reset --hard' checks out some files and 'git rebase' rewrites them again before applying commits. It's a redundant job.
Variant 2:

```
git branch -f tmp origin/master
git rebase --onto master master tmp
git branch -f master
git checkout master
```

Too many commands. I want to do this with just one command.

Comment: Could you write an alias for variant 2, reducing it to a single command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
git cherry-pick HEAD..origin/master
```

although cherry-pick is not as intellectual as rebase and will fail to discard commits (k,l,m) in this case:

```
     /--k---l---m---A---B---C origin/master
    /
D---E---k'--l'--m'---F---G *master
```